# Angular X editable only one row should be edit, if I click on next row edit previous row should reset to initial state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular X editable only one row should be edit, if I click on next row edit,    previous row should reset to initial state.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<h4>Angular-xeditable Editable row (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold">
      <td style="width:35%">Name</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Status</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Group</td>
      <td style="width:25%">Edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>
        <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
        <span editable-text="user.name" e-name="name" e-form="rowform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)" e-required>
          {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- editable status (select-local) -->
        <span editable-select="user.status" e-name="status" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
          {{ showStatus(user) }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- editable group (select-remote) -->
        <span editable-select="user.group" e-name="group" onshow="loadGroups()" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="g.id as g.text for g in groups">
          {{ showGroup(user) }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <!-- form -->
        <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="saveUser($data, user.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == user">
          <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
            save
          </button>
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
            cancel
          </button>
        </form>
        <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeUser($index)">del</button>
        </div>  
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addUser()">Add row</button>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable", "ngMockE2E"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
 $scope.users = [
    {id: 1, name: 'awesome user1', status: 2, group: 4, groupName: 'admin'},
    {id: 2, name: 'awesome user2', status: undefined, group: 3, groupName: 'vip'},
    {id: 3, name: 'awesome user3', status: 2, group: null}
  ]; 

  $scope.statuses = [
    {value: 1, text: 'status1'},
    {value: 2, text: 'status2'},
    {value: 3, text: 'status3'},
    {value: 4, text: 'status4'}
  ]; 

  $scope.groups = [];
  $scope.loadGroups = function() {
    return $scope.groups.length ? null : $http.get('/groups').success(function(data) {
      $scope.groups = data;
    });
  };

  $scope.showGroup = function(user) {
    if(user.group && $scope.groups.length) {
      var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.groups, {id: user.group});
      return selected.length ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
    } else {
      return user.groupName || 'Not set';
    }
  };

  $scope.showStatus = function(user) {
    var selected = [];
    if(user.status) {
      selected = $filter('filter')($scope.statuses, {value: user.status});
    }
    return selected.length ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
  };

  $scope.checkName = function(data, id) {
    if (id === 2 && data !== 'awesome') {
      return "Username 2 should be `awesome`";
    }
  };

  $scope.saveUser = function(data, id) {
    //$scope.user not updated yet
    angular.extend(data, {id: id});
    return $http.post('/saveUser', data);
  };

  // remove user
  $scope.removeUser = function(index) {
    $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
  };

  // add user
  $scope.addUser = function() {
    $scope.inserted = {
      id: $scope.users.length+1,
      name: '',
      status: null,
      group: null 
    };
    $scope.users.push($scope.inserted);
  };
});

// --------------- mock $http requests ----------------------
app.run(function($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/groups').respond([
    {id: 1, text: 'user'},
    {id: 2, text: 'customer'},
    {id: 3, text: 'vip'},
    {id: 4, text: 'admin'}
  ]);

  $httpBackend.whenPOST(/\/saveUser/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
    data = angular.fromJson(data);
    return [200, {status: 'ok'}];
  });
});
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
div[ng-app] { margin: 10px; }
.table {width: 100% }
form[editable-form] > div {margin: 10px 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i found solution for this just modifying some html and ctrl functions.

here is Angular xeditable working js fiddle link:- http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/19522/

here is code changes made:

```
<form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="saveUser($data, user.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline checkVisible" shown="inserted == user">
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
        save
      </button>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
        cancel
      </button>
    </form>
    <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editCall(rowform)">edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeUser($index)">del</button>
    </div>
```

CTRL changes:-

```
    $scope.editCall=function(rowform){
     if ( $( ".checkVisible" )
            .is( ":visible" ) ) {
    //alert("One row is active already");
    if(confirm("Are you sure, you want save current row and move to next row")){
    rowform.$show();
    }else{
        alert("Please save current row and move to next");
    }
    }else{
        rowform.$show();

       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I want to use what you have achieved, but when you do the rowfrom.$show() after the confirmation how would I $cancel() the visible rowform? I've tried a bunch of things and can't seem to get it working. Thanks in advance